# Customised Screen missing when package is exported

Tags: acumatica

There's something fishy with the way the projects are being exported. Say I have two companies, a production and test. I move customisation projects between them. From testing, I wrote a new screen MA.20.20.20. And under custom files, the ASP files are listed as follows.

[image]

Once working I exported this project, got the ZIP file and then imported into production. For some reason, my customised screen MA.20.20.20 is missing from the list in the production. It's just blank ! The ASP files are still listed though and I checked ZIP project. The physical files are still in there.

[image]

So what's am I doing wrong here?

TIA

Comment: By 2 companies I assume you are referring to 2 separate instances/sites? Are they the same versions? What happens if you add the files to a new project and just compare the project.xml entries to see what is different?

Comment: If you're using two companies within the same instance. I would suggest only editing it on 1 company, then using "Publish to multiple companies" in order to propagate the changes from your test company to your production company.

Comment: The files will be the same for all companies regardless of publish if using a single instance. If using a single instance this could be part of your problem. In general, customizations should be developed on a separate instance from production since there really is no "test" and "production" company within an instance as the files are applied to ALL companies (just a site and its files).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are referring to two different entries in the project. Your files are the pages in the pages directory while it seems like you also have screen modifications to your custom page files which I assume under customized screens would require a site map entry.

Are you including your sitemap entries in your customization project?

[image]

Comment: Yes, they're two different entries in the project. To demonstrate that the screens are dropped in the customized screens list when brought into another Advance instance. Also correct with regards to the sitemap entries. Every time a new screen is added, the sitemap entry is required. Which I reckon has something to do with the problem.

Comment: do you have your sitemap (and any supporting parent sitemap) entries in your project?

Comment: yep, problem is instead of showing the Site name( menu name), it's displaying the guid. Hence maybe why it's not showing the correct screen name.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzkD9.png

Comment: yea that is strange. You could try to delete those sitemap entries and republish? or publish without optimization settings found under multi- company publish.

Comment: I just ignored it and published the project anyway. There were no errors so that's good. When I went back to the project, screen ids are back ! Like it's self healing :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a little glitch in Acumatica. Publishing anyway ignoring this would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a permissions issue. Make sure your role has access to that particular screen. It's a bit strange as I would expect the screen to show within the Customization Project for the administrator but apparently it doesn't. I had faced a similar problem where in my local instance access permissions was Not Set for any roles and thus I could see the screen. But in production one of the roles had the access Revoked for the screen and thus even the admin couldn't see the screen even within the Customization Project.